# using hibernate listener after saveorupdate

Tags: hibernate, events, event-handling

in my project, some entities should have a signature property based on their values. For example, after creating an entity and filling its attributes, when `entity.saveorupdate()` method is called, hibernate event listener should take the control and gather the next sequence value for uniqueid from db. then the same event should produce a signature(lets say a String) based on entity attributes and this uniqueid. after sign, the real saveorupdate event should be called. So entity with sign attribute filled is written to database.

the problem is, in saveorupdate event, i do some work and call saveorupdate, so endless operation occurs.

do you have any solution about this kind of problem? (rather than using aspect oriented programming)

Answer (score 0):

A quick-and-dirty solution would be to have a `ThreadLocal` that holds the entity. If the threadlocal is empty - update the signature, set the threadlocal, and save the entity. On the next invocation the threadlocal will be filled and you can return from the listener.

Another thing you can do is  apply the listener before the actual `saveOrUpdate`, and skip if there is no ID. And manually invoke the logic when you create the entity (each subsequent update will be handled by the listener)